# Jenkins Pipeline Stages Duration of Previous Builds

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timeout, jenkins-pipeline, stage

I have been researching for a Jenkins Pipeline Plugin that has the capability of defining an absolute time for a particular stage and perform an action if that time is exceeded, but resulted in no luck.

Furthermore, I am trying to implement this functionality in groovy to attach it in the Pipeline script. I am using the **timeout** functionality with every stage in a try catch block. However, I would like to raise an exception not only if the time out is exceeded but also if when calculating the difference between duration of current stage and duration of a stage from a **previous build**, it exceeds a particular percentage. I would like to access a stage from a particular previous build together with its duration through the use of Jenkins Pipeline global variables. Till now, I couldn't find a way to access a stage from a particular build together with its duration.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can archive your stage runtime data in each build: `archive 'my-runtime.data'`. Then leverage `CopyArtifacts` plugin to copy those runtime-data artifacts to your current workspace:

```
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact'
   , projectName: JOB_NAME
   , selector: [$class: 'StatusBuildSelector']
   , filter: 'my-runtime.data'])
```

Simply parse that file (probably csv file), and leverage the data to perform your operation.

A longer term solution would be to create a plugin that handles this for folks with similar problems, but in the meantime you can leverage the above ideas.